# How to track if dexie UseLiveQuery is finished

Tags: reactjs, nest, dexie

I want to display a loader while a UseLiveQuery is not finished and display a "not found component" if the UseLiveQuery has returned an empty array.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easiest when your querier returns an array (see below). Then a result of undefined means still loading, while an empty array means finished loading but with zero results.

```
const friends = useLiveQuery (() => db.friends.toArray());
if (!friends) return <Spinner />; // Still loading

return <ul>{
  friends.map(friend => <li key={friend.id}>
    {friend.name}, {friend.age}
  </li>)
}</ul>;
```

But if your querier returns the result from [table.get()](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.get()), a value of undefined could both mean that query is still loading or that the requested id was not found. To distinguish between the two, you could let the querier return something that makes it easier to distinguish between the two. For example, let the querier return the result as an item in an array and supply a third argument to [useLiveQuery()](https://dexie.org/docs/dexie-react-hooks/useLiveQuery()) with an empty array (something else than undefined) as a default result.

```
const [friend, loaded] = useLiveQuery (
  () => db.friends.get(1).then(friend => [friend, true]),
  [], // deps...
  []  // default result: makes 'loaded' undefined while loading
);

if (!loaded) return <Spinner />; // Still loading...
if (!friend) return <NotFound ... />; // Loaded but friend not found

return <>{friend.name}, {friend.age}</>; // Loaded and friend found.
```

*That said, you'll normally not need a spinner when querying indexedDB (unless for very complex queries). In this case, probably better to just return `null` instead of `<Spinner />`, to bother the end-user the least.*

Comment: This is a correct answer that has helped me solve my problem. Thank you! Unfortunately I can't upvote you because I don't have enough reputation but I have marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Is this working after the first load too? Initially, at the first data load every is cool, but after the the user filters get changed, the result never goes back to undefined during the loading. So I have no way to rely on the undefined to know when it's loading. 

I'm asking cause my query takes a little less than 1 sec and it actually needs a loader.

Comment: @FrancescoMeli Unfortunately I made the choice to not flicker on changed deps but keep old result until new value arrives. However, you can build a hook based on useState(), useEffect() and liveQuery(...).subscribe() that would behave your requested way. Pass the deps to useEffect(). In it, do `setResult(defaultValue); const o = liveQuery(querier).subscribe(result => setResult(result)); return ()=>o.unsubscribe();`. This will emit the undefined (or default value) whenever deps change.

Answer (score 1):

I created a wrapper (React) hook to provide this kind of behaviour with Dexie.js. It is fully typed using TypeScript.
It also accounts for missing data (for example, if you .get() using a key not present in IndexedDB) and has a different return type when handling arrays (because in that case we can never have an undefined data result).

```
import {MySubClassedDexie, useDexieDb} from "@/providers/dexieProvider/dexieProvider";
import {useLiveQuery} from "dexie-react-hooks";

export enum Status {
    PENDING = 'pending',
    RESOLVED = 'resolved'
}

export type AsyncLiveQueryReturn<T = any> = AsyncLiveQueryReturnPending | AsyncLiveQueryReturnResolved<T>;

export interface AsyncLiveQueryReturnPending {
    isLoading: true;
    isSuccess: false;
    status: Status.PENDING;
    data: null;
}

export interface AsyncLiveQueryReturnResolved<T = any> {
    isLoading: false;
    isSuccess: true;
    status: Status.RESOLVED;
    data: T extends Array<infer U> ? Array<U> : (T | undefined);
}

const useAsyncLiveQuery = <T>(querier: (db: MySubClassedDexie) => Promise<T>, deps: any[] = [], defaultIfMissing?: T): AsyncLiveQueryReturn<T> => {
    const db = useDexieDb();

    const [data, status] = useLiveQuery(() => {
        return querier(db).then((data: T) => {
            const d = data === undefined ? defaultIfMissing : data;
            return [d, Status.RESOLVED]
        })
    }, deps, [null, Status.PENDING])


    return {
        isLoading: status === Status.PENDING,
        isSuccess: status === Status.RESOLVED,
        status,
        data,
    } as AsyncLiveQueryReturn<T>;
};

export default useAsyncLiveQuery;
```

You use it as follows:

```
const {isLoading, isSuccess, data} = useAsyncLiveQuery(db => db.items.get(myId), [myId], myFallbackObject);
```

I hope this helps somebody!